# Withdraw EUR from Paypal to Unverified Bank Account in Germany

Tags: paypal, european-union

I have a bank account in Germany, and I have a Paypal account with <10k EUR in it. I want to know if it is possible to withdraw everything into my bank account if it is not verified with Paypal.

Comment: Did you *try*?  That's the first thing I'd do.  If it doesn't work, then verify the account.

Comment: What's the problem with verifying it ? (if you have online banking you can probably get this done in less than an hour)